# Are relevant additional reference links added by anonymous users valid?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4546759 where an anonymous user had added a relevant link [PHP stdClass: Storing Data in an Object Instead of an Array](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/) to the accepted answer of a protected question. The edit was subsequently rejected as `vandalism`. Is this the proper way to deal with such?

Comment: Yes.  Someone's just trying to stick in spam links to his content into someone else's highly viewed content.  The user that approved this spam edit might need a bit of a time out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They *can* be OK; but they should be very relevant, and not spammy in nature.

Just adding in a link to some random website that happens to mention the topic generally smells a lot to me. I *tend* only to approve such edits when they are linking to a canonical, authoritative reference. From a vendor or official support area, for example.

In the specific case you cite, I definitely think that smells spammy.